# Is there a way to instantiate a class from an object of it's super class without assigning all the variables manually?

Tags: dart

Say I have 2 classes:

```
class User {
  String name;
  String age;
  DateTime birthDate;
  User(this.name);
}

class Teacher extends User {
 String className;
 Teacher(String name): super(name);
 Teacher.fromUser(User user, this.className): super(user.name);
}
```

Doing the following is easy. But what if the super class has 30 fields? Is there a way to make a constructor that will copy all the variables over without having to do:

```
Teacher.fromUser(User user) {
    this.id = user.id;
    this.firstName = user.firstName;
    this.lastName = user.lastName;
    this.gender = user.gender;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No.
There is no way to automatically copy fields from one object to another.

If you have more than one class needing the behavior, you can add a `copyFrom(User)` on the `User` class which copies all the fields, and then just call `this.copyFrom(user)` on the subclasses. Then you will, at least, only have to write the code once.

Comment: It's just a bunch of separate subclasses being made. The program I'm working on made classes too generic and since I don't want to break existing code, I'm extending the classes to contain missing fields. These classes have a bunch of fields and I'm writing functions to convert the existing objects to the new objects. I just didn't want to have to duplicate the long constructor for each class